# Render html table with underscore template engine using a backbone model

Tags: json, backbone.js, underscore.js

I'm trying to simply display some JSON using Underscore and Backbone. Following are the codes. I am getting some parsing error for the template I have used. The error is like this: "The content of elements must consist of well-formed character data or markup." Any help is appreciated:

Following is the JSON object I have:

```
[  { name: 'mem1 mem1', 
     enrolmentDate: '12 May 2023', 
     optOutExpiryDate: '17 May 2023', 
     enrolmentType: 'Without qualifying earnings', 
     paymentSource: 'pmtSrc', 
     group: 'grp' 
   }, 
   { name: 'mem2 mem2', 
     enrolmentDate: '21 Jan 2022', 
     optOutExpiryDate: '26 Jan 2022', 
     enrolmentType: 'Without qualifying earnings', 
     paymentSource: 'pmtSrc', group: 'grp' 
   }
];
```

Following is the template:

```
<script id="workerTemplate" type="text/template">
<td><&percnt;&equals; name &percnt;></td>
<td><&percnt;&equals; enrolmentDate &percnt;></td>
<td><&percnt;&equals; optOutExpiryDate &percnt;></td>
<td><&percnt;&equals; enrolmentType &percnt;></td>
<td><&percnt;&equals; paymentSource &percnt;></td>
<td><&percnt;&equals; group &percnt;></td>
</script>
```

Following is the table in which the JSON datas need to be displayed:

```
<table id="addAndSearchActiveMemberTableId"             styleClass="table_cont_shedule worker_table col_align" rowClasses="odd,even">
                                        <thead>
                                            <tr>
                                            <th class="name" scope="col">Name</th>
                                            <th class="enrol_date" scope="col">Enrolment date</th>
                                            <th class="oo_exp_date" scope="col">Opt out expiry date</th>
                                            <th class="enrol_type" scope="col">Enrolment type</th>
                                            <th class="pay_src" scope="col">Payment source</th>
                                            <th class="grp" scope="col">Group</th>
                                            </tr>
                                        </thead>
                                        <tbody id="workers">
                                        </tbody>
                                    </table>


Follwing is the JavaScript using backbone framework:

                <script type="text/javascript">

                  var app = app || {};
                //This is the backbone model of worker
                  app.Worker = Backbone.Model.extend({
                      defaults: {
                          name: 'None',
                          enrolmentDate: 'None',
                          optOutExpiryDate: 'None',
                          enrolmentType: 'None',
                          paymentSource: 'None',
                          group: 'None'
                      }
                  });

//this is workerlist
                  app.WorkerList = Backbone.Collection.extend({
                        model: app.Worker
                  });


//The workerView
                  app.WorkerView = Backbone.View.extend({
                        tagName: 'tr',
                        className: '',
                        template: _.template( $( '#workerTemplate' ).html() ),

                        render: function() {
//this.el is what we defined in tagName. use $el to get access to jQuery html() function
                            window.alert("I am in render function of WorkerView");
                            this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );

                            return this;
                        }
                    }); 


//The workerListView
                  app.WorkerListView = Backbone.View.extend({
                        el: '#workers',

                        initialize: function( initialWorkers ) {
                            window.alert("initialize method called");
                            this.collection = new app.WorkerList( initialWorkers );
                            this.render();

                        },

// render workerCollection by rendering each worker in its collection
                        render: function() {
                            this.collection.each(function( item ) {
                                window.alert("calling renderWorker from render function of WorkerListView");
                                this.renderWorker( item );
                            }, this );
                        },

// render a worker by creating a workerView and appending the
// element it renders to the workerCollection's element
                        renderWorker: function( item ) {
                            window.alert("I am in renderWorker of WorkerListView");
                            var workerView = new app.WorkerView({
                                model: item
                            });
                            this.$el.append( workerView.render().el );
                        }
                    });

                  $(function() {

                        window.alert("function invoked");
                        var workers = [
                            { name: 'mem1 mem1', enrolmentDate: '12 May 2023', optOutExpiryDate: '17 May 2023', enrolmentType: 'Without qualifying earnings', paymentSource: 'pmtSrc', group: 'grp' },
                            { name: 'mem2 mem2', enrolmentDate: '21 Jan 2022', optOutExpiryDate: '26 Jan 2022', enrolmentType: 'Without qualifying earnings', paymentSource: 'pmtSrc', group: 'grp' }
                        ];
                        window.alert("Data passed to WorkerListView");
                        new app.WorkerListView( workers );
                    });
                  </script>


Now the question is:Is this the correct way to implement? It's not working :( 
 what are the flaws in the code. I have tried the code in html page, it's working fine , but in xhtml it's not working.
```

Comment: Is your template actually *html escaped*, or was that just from copying and pasting into your question?

Comment: No, it is as I copied here.

Answer (score 2):

You need to *unescape* your template in order for underscore to be able to interpolate the values passed in. Try the following template:

```
<script id="workerTemplate" type="text/template">
<td><%= name %></td>
<td><%= enrolmentDate %></td>
<td><%= optOutExpiryDate %></td>
<td><%= enrolmentType %></td>
<td><%= paymentSource %></td>
<td><%= group %></td>
</script>
```

In addition it's better practice to call [model.toJSON()](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-toJSON) rather then passing in the attributes directly.

So instead of:

```
this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.attributes ) );
```

you should be calling:

```
 this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON()) );
```

Here's a link to a [jsBin](http://output.jsbin.com/sequyijuhe/1/)

Comment: @muistooshort thanks for pointing that out, I'll modify my answer accordingly.  I was sure that I reproduced the OP's error and that it was resolved when I changed from passing in the attributes directly to calling toJSON, but I'm unable to reproduce it now.

Comment: @Jack: My code is absolutely working fine in html page, but when I am trying it in xhtml page(as mostly I am using JSF framework for my project and tring to make a hybrid), the template is getting parsing error. Does xhtml dont parse correctly the template in <script> tag? Then what is the proper way to implement it in xhtml page?

Comment: @Shahid I just modified the doctype to the [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/jometogegu/2/) to xhtml and it still works. Is there perhaps something else on your page that isn't valid xhtml?

Comment: @Jack : The xhtml I am using does not look like
<head></head>
<body></body>
What I observed,  you have included the js libraries i.e. (<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/backbone.js/1.1.2/backbone-min.js"></script>) in the head of the xhtml page, whereas I have included in the jsf <form> tag which is in ui facelet tag.


Is this the reason for parsing error?

Comment: @Shahid I don't think it should make a difference, the reason the scripts are in the head in the jsbin is because when you add a script in a jsbin it by default places it in the head. As long as they are included before they are used (you do want to make sure that underscore is included before backbone though).